# Script to group numbered files into folders

Tags: file, shell, unix, scripting, directory

I have around a million files in one folder in the form xxxx_description.jpg where xxx is a number ranging from 100 to an unknown upper.

The list is similar to this:

`146467_description1.jpg
146467_description2.jpg
146467_description3.jpg
146467_description4.jpg
14646_description1.jpg
14646_description2.jpg
14646_description3.jpg
146472_description1.jpg
146472_description2.jpg
146472_description3.jpg
146500_description1.jpg
146500_description2.jpg
146500_description3.jpg
146500_description4.jpg
146500_description5.jpg
146500_description6.jpg`

To get the file number down in the at folder I'd like to put them all into folders grouped by the number at the start.

ie:
`146467/146467_description1.jpg
146467/146467_description2.jpg
146467/146467_description3.jpg
146467/146467_description4.jpg
14646/14646_description1.jpg
14646/14646_description2.jpg
14646/14646_description3.jpg
146472/146472_description1.jpg
146472/146472_description2.jpg
146472/146472_description3.jpg
146500/146500_description1.jpg
146500/146500_description2.jpg
146500/146500_description3.jpg
146500/146500_description4.jpg
146500/146500_description5.jpg
146500/146500_description6.jpg`

I was thinking to try and use command line: find | awk {} | mv command  or maybe write a script, but I'm not sure how to do this most efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really are dealing with millions of files, I suspect that a glob (`*.jpg` or `[0-9]*_*.jpg` may fail because it makes a command line that's too long for the shell.  If that's the case, you can still use `find`.  Something like this might work:

```
find /path -name "[0-9]*_*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mkdir -p "/target/${f%_*}"; mv "$f" "/target/${f%_*}/"' \;
```

Broken out for easier reading, this is what we're doing:

- `find /path` - run find, with `/path` as a starting point,
- `-name "[0-9]*_*.jpg"` - match files that match this filespec in all directories,
- `-exec sh -c` execute the following on each file...

  - `'f="{}";` - put the filename into a variable...
  - `mkdir -p "/target/${f%_*}";` - make a target directory based on that variable (read mkdir's man page about the `-p` option)
  - `mv "$f" "/target/${f%_*}/"'` - move the file into the directory.
  - `\;` - end the `-exec` expression

On the up side, it can handle any number of files that `find` can handle (i.e. limited only by your OS).  On the down side, it's launching a separate shell for each file to be handled.

**Note that the above answer is for Bourne/POSIX/Bash**.  If you're using CSH or TCSH as your shell, the following might work instead:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach f (*_*.jpg)
  set split = ($f:as/_/ /)
  mkdir -p "$split[1]"
  mv "$f" "$split[1]/"
end
```

This assumes that the filespec will fit in tcsh's glob buffer.  I've tested with 40000 files (894KB) on one command line and not had a problem using /bin/sh or /bin/csh in FreeBSD.
Like the Bourne/POSIX/Bash parameter expansion solution above, this avoids unnecessary calls to external I haven't tested that, and would recommend the `find` solution even though it's slower.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was trying to do myself. Yes, I really am dealing with just over a million files in one folder. :(
Some decisions are bad years later....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
for i in [0-9]*_*.jpg; do
   p=`echo "$i" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)_.*/\1/'`
   mkdir -p "$p"
   mv "$i" "$p"
done
```

Comment: I expect that if there are millions of files, the expansion of that glob will be too much for the shell.  Do you know the line length limit?

Comment: That would seem to be a problem, then.  :)

Comment: Also, even if this isn't too long for the OP's shell (which is unspecified), you're launching three processes for each file.  Using `sed` for this is wasteful.

Comment: No, as you noted, the OP tagged his question "shell", not CSH, Bash, POSIX, Bourne, KSH, or any other specific shell.  Your answer works in one particular shell (or family of them), but you didn't mention which one.  (Yes, it's obvious to those of us who know, but isn't it better to be specific, rather than make assumptions?)

Comment: It is better we concentrate on important things rather than wasting time on this useless argument :) I will delete my comments from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

```
   for file in *.jpg; 
    do 
    dirName=$(echo $file | grep -oE '^[0-9]+')
    [[ -d $dirName ]] || mkdir $dirName
    mv $file $dirName
    done
```

`grep -oE '^[0-9]+'` extracts the starting digits in the filename as

```
146467
146467
146467
146467
14646
...
```

`[[ -d $dirName ]]` returns `1` if the directory exists

`[[ -d $dirName ]] || mkdir $dirName` ensures that the `mkdir` works only if the test `[[ -d $dirName ]]` fails, that is the direcotry does not exists

Comment: Although it works, this answer products a lot of "directory exists" messages.

Comment: I have corrected the answer. Hopes it workes fine now